# How can I use one argument as the default value for another?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I'd like to define a command that takes 1, 2 or 3 arguments, and where the 2nd gets the same value as the 1st if it is not defined. I tried

```
\newcommand\codefrom[3][#1][Matlab]{ ... }
```

but I get an error saying

> ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \codefrom.
>   <to be read again>
>                      1
>   l.57 \newcommand{\codefrom}[3][#1][
>                                                                 Matlab]

Is there any way to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: Sheesh, three answers in thirty seconds.  Nice question, Tomas.

Comment: In 2020, you may want to consider pulling the _now_ [best answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51775/3213) (?) up to help people landing here from search. Thanks!

Comment: I'm reluctant to making such a change without verifying that it actually works - and since I no longer work with TeX (this question is almost 10 years old!) I have no reason (or incentive...) to spend time on this. Isn't that what votes are for?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't accomplish this with one `\newcommand`. There you can define one optional parameter, and it has to be the first one. There is the `twoopt` package that defines `\newcommandtwoopt` for two optional parameters, but I don't think it can handle what you want to achieve. I first thought you would need to use TeX's `\def`, but here's a solution that's completely free of any `\def`s and `@`s:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\newcommand\storefirst{}
\newcommand\storesecond{}
\newcommand\codefrom[1]{\renewcommand\storefirst{#1}\codefromi}
\newcommand\codefromi[1][\storefirst]{\renewcommand\storesecond{#1}\codefromii}
\newcommand\codefromii[1][Matlab]{\storefirst, \storesecond, #1}
\begin{document}
\codefrom{first}\par
\codefrom{first}[second]\par
\codefrom{first}[second][third]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant! This works exactly as I want it to, and is simple enough to understand =) Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a problem with this solution. If you type `\codefrom{first} Hello` you'll get something like _"first, first, MatlabHello"_ (note the missing space). The same with the other examples. Is there a easy solution to this? Otherwise, it is indeed a very nice answer.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Use the following snippet (~ is a non-breaking space): \codefrom{first}~Hello

Answer (score 15):

Here is a solution based on `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\codefrom{moO{Matlab}}{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \codefromaux{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }{%
    \codefromaux{#1}{#1}{#3}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\codefromaux{mmm}{%
  1 = #1, 2 = #2, 3 = #3%
}

\begin{document}

\codefrom{a}\par
\codefrom{a}[b]\par
\codefrom{a}[b][c]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very interesting. Could you elaborate a bit on the `moO`? (I think I can guess what it means, but still some confirmation would be great.)

Comment: `m` = mandatory argument, `o` = optional argument (square brackets) with no default value, `O` = optional argument (square brackets) with default value as given. There was recently a question about trying to be able to use the value of one argument directly as the default for a second in `xparse`: currently, I've not come up with a good way to do it, I'm afraid.

Comment: With the latest `xparse` (not yet on CTAN) one can replace the signature by `m O{#1} O{Matlab}` to directly have the second argument default to the first (no need for `\IfValueTF` then (basically Patrick Häcker's answer is now actually supported).

Answer (score 15):

The question is old, but as all answers are unnecessary complicated, I want to provide a simpler solution using xparse's possibilities directly.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
    \NewDocumentCommand{\codefrom}{mO{#1}O{Matlab}}{#1, #2, #3}
    \codefrom{a} \quad \codefrom{a}[b] \quad \codefrom{a}[b][c]
\end{document}
```

The result is [image]. The first argument is `m`andatory, the second and third ones are `O`ptional. The second argument's default value is the first argument, the third argument's default value is Matlab.

Comment: It might be useful for others to know that it appears that only earlier arguments may be referenced this way. For example, I can't get this to work: `{O{#2}m}`. That tries to insert a literal "#2".

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev with the latest `xparse` (not yet on CTAN) what you describe is supported (in fact, until now we had not explicitly supported the syntax described in the answer).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, but you have to "roll your own", so to speak.  (You should note that even the sort of optional arguments you see in various core LaTeX macros, like the ones which take two optionals, are not supported by the `\newcommand` syntax).

The basic mechanism is to use `\@ifnextchar` to figure out whether there is an optional argument, filling it in if not, and then calling an internal macro which doesn't take an optional argument.  In your case the following seems reasonable (note: written on the fly):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\codefrom}[1]{
 \@ifnextchar[
   {\codefrom@firstinner{#1}}
   {\codefrom@firstinner{#1}[#1]}
}

\def\codefrom@firstinner#1[#2]{
 \@ifnextchar[
   {\codefrom@secondinner{#1}{#2}}
   {\codefrom@secondinner{#1}{#2}[Matlab]}
}

\def\codefrom@secondinner#1#2[#3]{
 ...
}
\makeatother
```

As you can see, at each step it checks for a `[` and, if it is not present, fills in the argument with the desired default.  The last step has all the arguments, and continues the process.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\codefrom}[1][]{\def\c@defr@m{#1}\c@defrom}
\newcommand{\c@defrom}[2][\c@defr@m]{\message{[\c@defr@m,#1,#2]}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\codefrom{a}
\codefrom[a]{b}
\codefrom[a][b]{c}
\end{document}
```

Edit: An alternative, if it is important for you to access the parameters as #1–#3:

```
\newcommand{\codefrom}[1][]{\def\c@defr@m{#1}\c@defrom}
\newcommand{\c@defrom}[1][\c@defr@m]
  {\expandafter\@codefrom\expandafter{\c@defr@m}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@codefrom}[3]{\message{[#1,#2,#3]}}
```

Comment: This is great, and *almost* what I need =) The output now shows `[,,a] [a,a,b] [a,b,c]`, but I'd like it to be `[a,a,a] [a,a,b] [a,b,c]` (or with some permutation of it). Also, I don't see where the `\c@defr@om` command comes from, but your MWE compiles on my machine...

Comment: What `\c@defr@om` command? I neither use nor define one. I admit these names are hard to read and keep apart, though. I guess I have been badly influenced by lots of other (La)TeX code that uses the s@me s@rt of n@ming convention. Anyway, having #3 be the default value of #1 and #2 was not in your original specification. I don't have the time right now to come up with a good way to do that, but it is probably most easily achieved in a final processing step – if you're happy with a solution that treats [] the same way as if the optional parameter had been skipped.

Comment: +1 for the idea to use repeated `\newcommand` s.