# Parsing optional macro arguments

Tags: macros

I am trying to define a macro with flexible arguments: 3 mandatory and 2 optional ones - like this:

```
\macro{<enter code here>}[arg2] arg3 = arg4 | arg5;
```

So args 2 and 5 are optional, as is the `|`.

I got quiet close to solving this with ideas found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402354/split-comma-separated-parameters-in-latex).

Now I am stuck somewhere in TeX's stomach. Maybe someone can shed some light on the problem - I am a total newbie and I think, there must be plenty of possibilities. I have [tried a lot](http://sprunge.us/fDSR) but am not familiar enough with `\expandafter`, `\futurelet`, `\xdef` & friends. I am stuck here:

```
\makeatother
\def\@pop#1{}
\def\@split#1;{\def\@@tmp{#1|}\expandafter\@@split\@@tmp\@end@token}
\def\@@split#1|{\@ifnextchar\@end@token{{#1}{}\@pop}{\@@@split{#1}}}
\def\@@@split#1#2|{{#1}{#2}\@pop}

\def\display#1{\@ifnextchar[{\@display{#1}}{\@display{#1}[1]}}
\def\@display#1[#2]#3={\def\@tmp{\@@display{#1}{#2}{#3}}\expandafter\@tmp\@split}

\def\@@display#1#2#3#4#5{*#1*#2*#3*#4*#5*}
\makeatletter

\display{aaa}[bbb] AAA = BBB | CCC;
```

the output is supposed to look like this:

```
*aaa*bbb*AAA*BBB*CCC*
```

but instead I get

```
/tmp/problem.tex:56: Missing control sequence inserted.
&lt;inserted text&gt;
                \inaccessible 
l.42 \display{aaa} AAA = BBB;
```

...am using a href="http://gummi.midnightcoding.org/"gummi/a ...good stuff IMHO!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solution using LaTeX2e just for `\@ifnextchar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\display#1{%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\display@aux@i{#1}}
    {\display@aux@i{#1}[]}%
}
\def\display@aux@i#1[#2]#3=#4;{%
  \display@aux@ii{#1}{#2}{#3}#4||\@nil
}
\def\display@aux@ii#1#2#3#4|#5|#6\@nil{%
  *#1*#2*#3*#4*#5*
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent
\display{aaa}[bbb] AAA = BBB | CCC; \\
\display{aaa}[bbb] AAA = BBB ;
\end{document}
```

Alternative [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpackages)-based solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand \display 
  { m o u { = } > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { | } } u { ; } } {
  * #1 * #2 * #3 * \display_aux:nn #4 *  
}
\cs_new:Npn \display_aux:nn #1#2 { #1 * #2 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\noindent
\display{aaa}[bbb] AAA = BBB | CCC; \\
\display{aaa}[bbb] AAA = BBB ;
\end{document}
```

Comment: I felt that there would be an easy solution but I certainly didn't expect it to be THAT simple and I didn't expect it to turn up here THAT fast. Have you got some kind of "TEX-goggles" to see this? I tried hard to wrap my head around that ... *amazed* :-) ...thanks A LOT!

Comment: @Patrick. There are some well-known techniques for parsing optional material, which both Herbert and I have used. In the case of the `[...]`, the key is to use `\@ifnextchar`, which you already knew. For the second optional argument, as the `;` has to be there it is best to grab everything then re-parse the last argument looking for a `|`. By using _two_ of these and an appropriate end point you can avoid needing to test for `|` explicitly. The method is to use `#4|#5|#6\@nil` (or similar), with `#6` as a dummy argument that is thrown away.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I have a small follow-up question concerning \@ifnextchar: I understand that is not in core (knuth) tex bit in some latex ... addon? I am not sure if i looked in the right place because it is not easy to find with find | grep. Do you know by heart in which file the definition is ? And maybe you could give me a rough idea of how it works... ? :-) just curios

Comment: @Patrick. That would count as 'a separate question' :-). It's defined in `latex.ltx`.

Answer (score 5):

the same, only the other way round :-)

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\makeatletter
\def\display#1{\@ifnextchar[{\display@i{#1}}{\display@i{#1}[]}}
\def\display@i#1[#2]#3;{\display@ii#3||\@nil{#1}[#2]}
\def\display@ii#1=#2|#3|#4\@nil#5[#6]{*#5*#6*#1*#2*#3*}

\def\blub{\@ifnextchar[\blub@i{\blub@i[]}}
\def\blub@i[#1]#2;{\blub@ii[#1]#2++\@nil}
\def\blub@ii[#1]#2+#3+#4\@nil{blub[#1] & #2 & #3}
\makeatother


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\display{aaa}[bbb] AAA = BBB|CCC;

\display{aaa}[bbb] AAA = BBB;

\end{document}
```

Comment: All right ... nice compilation of parsing techniques now.

Comment: Another Patrick - welcome :)

Answer (score 5):

You have already received valid LaTeX solution, but for someone else who wants to do something similar in ConTeXt, I am including a ConTeXt solution. This is essential similar to LaTeX solutions using `\@ifnextchar`, but use a higher level macro `\dodoubleargument` that checks for two optional arguments (ConTeXt also provides other variants of `\do...argument`: `single`, `double`, `triple`, `quadruple`, `quintuple`, `sixtuple`, and `seventuple`).

```
\def\Macro#1%
  {\dodoubleargument\doMacro[#1]}

\def\doMacro[#1][#2]#3=#4;%
  {\dostartMacro{#1}{#2}{#3}#4||\dostopMacro}

\def\dostartMacro#1#2#3#4|#5|#6\dostopMacro
  {*#1*#2*#3*#4*#5*}

\starttext
\startlines
\Macro{aaa} AAA = BBB ;
\Macro{aaa} AAA = BBB | CCC ;
\Macro{aaa}[bbb] AAA = BBB ;
\Macro{aaa}[bbb] AAA = BBB | CCC; 
\stoplines
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's yet another LaTeX solution not unlike [this related answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5211/how-can-i-use-one-argument-as-the-default-value-for-another/5213#5213); the new feature is that it's completely free of explicit calls of `\@ifnextchar`. (This also makes `\makeatletter` / `\makeatother` dispensable, so maybe it's a bit more accessible for the end user.)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand\display[1]{*#1*\displayi}
\newcommand\displayi[1][]{#1*\displayii}
\def\displayii#1=#2;{#1*\displayiii#2||;}
\def\displayiii#1|#2|#3;{#1*#2}
\begin{document}
\display{aaa} AAA = BBB | CCC; \par
\display{aaa}[bbb] AAA = BBB | CCC; \par
\display{aaa}[bbb] AAA = BBB ;
\end{document}
```

Note that I used the fact that the arguments `#1` to `#5` occur in their natural order in the replacement of `\display`; this could be adjusted if needed.

Comment: Well, it uses `\@ifnextchar` within `\displayi`, although you don't see it :-)

Comment: `\newcommand` is a high level LaTeX macro and it uses more than an internal `\@ifnextchar` ...

Comment: @Joseph, @Herbert: I know, and in the end, `\futurelet` will be used. I'll try and improve the wording.

Comment: @Herbert: I think using `\newcommand` if possible is better _because_ it does more, e.g. testing if the macro is already defined. This advantage is of course somewhat lost as I use `\def` later on, anyway.

Comment: I like this one because it beats my blub() by 12 chars, parsing 5 (not only 3) args and avoids \makeatother. Who cares about "plain tex" ? :-) I have been digging into the sources a bit now...

Comment: @Patrick: Of course I can beat it _because_ I use LaTeX's `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 3):

I learned a lot - now let me show off this pure TeX version, using \futurelet:
(if you can shorten it, feel free to edit)

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\b{\ba[]}
\def\ba[#1]#2;{\bar{#1}#2++\nil}
\def\bar#1#2+#3+#4\nil{blub[#1]&#2&#3}
\def\blu{\ifx\next[\let\f\ba\else\let\f\b\fi\f}
\def\blub{\futurelet\next\blu}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\blub foo;                  \\
\blub[bla] bar;                     \\
\blub foo + bar;            \\
\blub[bla] foo + bar;               \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Oh ... i was just wondering how remote images can NOT be disabled ...
[image]

Comment: @Patrick: I do not really know what you want to achieve with your code, but the one added to my answer does the same.

Comment: @Herbert: This was just a "research project" whose goal was to solve the problem in "pure tex". I mean the tex core application binary macro engine, written in c most probably (want to study it...), without any "latex or other tex .sty libraries loaded. A solution using only tex "primitives". (quoting Donald Knuth in "The Texbook", page 9: "About 300 of TEX’s control sequences are called primitive; these are the low-level atomic operations that are not decomposable into simpler functions.")

Comment: @Patrick. TeX82 is written in Pascal, using the WEB system. Knuth never expected you just to use primitives, and indeed much of 'plain TeX' is macros, not primitives. Things like `\@ifnextchar` are ultimately defined in primitives, of course, as LaTeX is a macro package on top of TeX (the engine) and not a modified binary.

Comment: the tex/latex source is a bit scary as you find more than a dozen unpopular file extensions like ".sty" ".ltx" and such stuff in the archive. and i had a tough time locating my "binary" i was looking for. thought it would be part of texlife. finally found branches/stable/source/src/texk/web2c/pdftexdir/pdftex.web in the pdftex project - http://foundry.supelec.fr/gf/project/pdftex/. so tex is written in web is written in c (originally pascal). huh. i'm glad i finally took the time to find this out :-)

Comment: pdftex.web is derived from http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/systems/knuth/dist/tex/tex.web. and web is converted to c these days with "web2c" ... but in tex82 is used to be converted to pascal (correct?) and what was the name of that system again? ... anyway ... the last thing i wonder now, is...

Comment: ...is: are only .web files "woven" into the final binary and all .tex files are parsed in the beginning of each run? (i'm asking because my pdflatex is really fast... no perceptible invocation overhead) and secondly: is the an overview somehow somewhere of the meaning of all those file extensions in the latex source tree ? (i mean e.g. in texlive/Master/texmf: 10 sty 18 enc 21 tcx 22 map 23 tlu 35 cfg 55 tex 366 asy 425 xdy ... are the ones i'm not familiar with

Comment: ok, .tex i know :-) and i checked again - it's close to 1000 (!) different file extensions :-O http://sprunge.us/XcCM

Comment: minor flaw fixed: http://sprunge.us/KDJh - 922 different extensions