# How to detect if \thepage is undefined?

Tags: conditionals, page-numbering, incompatibility

The [`sig-alternate`](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates) class by default disables page numbers, which breaks `mparhack` (amongst other things).

How can I include tex code only if `\thepage` is properly defined? I tried `\ifcsname` and `\ifcsempty` of `etoolbox`, but neither worked.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

%\pagenumbering{arabic}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mparhack}

\begin{document}

\title{A Sample {\ttlit ACM} SIG Proceedings Paper in LaTeX}

\numberofauthors{1} 
\author{
\alignauthor
Ben Trovato\titlenote{Dr.~Trovato insisted his name be first.}\\
       \affaddr{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}\\
       \affaddr{1932 Wallamaloo Lane}\\
       \affaddr{Wallamaloo, New Zealand}\\
       \email{trovato@corporation.com}
}
\date{30 July 1999}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

The \textit{proceedings} are the records of a conference.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `expl3` and the command `IfNoValueTF`, from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9540/parsing-optional-macro-arguments?rq=1. This requires the `xparse` package.

Comment: No success, `IfNoValueTF` always goes into the false-branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\@ifundefined`:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mparhack}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{thepage}{\def\thepage{\arabic{page}}}{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{A Sample {\ttlit ACM} SIG Proceedings Paper in LaTeX}

\numberofauthors{1}
\author{
\alignauthor
Ben Trovato\titlenote{Dr.~Trovato insisted his name be first.}\\
       \affaddr{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}\\
       \affaddr{1932 Wallamaloo Lane}\\
       \affaddr{Wallamaloo, New Zealand}\\
       \email{trovato@corporation.com}
}
\date{30 July 1999}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

The \textit{proceedings} are the records of a conference.
\end{document}
```

Works with or without `\pagenumbering{arabic}`.

Comment: Is there a version to test if a package was already loaded? A kind of `\@ifloaded{}`?

Comment: @Sigur `\@ifpackageloaded{<package>}{<true>}{<false>}`