# How to check if \thepage is gobbled?

Tags: page-numbering

I am using `\pagenumbering{gobble}` to hide page numbers in some pages. I am also using `fancyhdr` and `lastpage` packages to show page numbers for other pages like -

```
Page \thepage of \pageref{LastPage}
```

However for gobbled pages it shows something like -

```
Page of 4 %only last page number is shown
```

I want to hide the whole thing when `\thepage` is gobbled.

What I have tried so far is -

```
\rfoot{\ifnum \thepage>0 Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}\else \fi}
```

This compiles and works as intended, but there is a error message when `\newpage` is incountered.

> Missing number, treated as zero. \newpage

I have also tried to use `\@ifundefined` as was suggested in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176001/41544) but couldn't get it to work

Can anyone suggest any ideas?

Here's a compilable sample document source.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% default is 0pt

\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}

\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\ifnum \thepage>0 Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}\else \fi}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    First Page
    \newpage
    Second Page
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    Third Page
    \newpage
    Forth Page
\end{document}
```

I am using `portable miketex` for windows.

Comment: Can you post a compilable document, please?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer updated question.

Comment: You can also use `\fancyhf{}` to clear all the fields instead of `\lhead{}` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See the update at the end of the answer,please**

Using `\meaning\thepage` reveals that

`\thepage` is defined as `\csname @gobble\endcsname \c@page`

if `\pagenumbering{gobble}` was applied.

This definition can be used in a `\ifx...` conditional statement to check whether precisely this has been done, i.e.

```
\makeatletter
    \rfoot{\def\foo{\csname @gobble\endcsname \c@page}
    \ifx\thepage\foo
    % Yes, it is gobbled!
    % Perhaps some other statement here? 
    \else 
    Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}%
    \fi
 }% End of \rfoot
\makeatother
```

The `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair is needed for the `\@gobble` macro names having the `@`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% default is 0pt

\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}

\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\makeatletter
\rfoot{\def\foo{\csname @gobble\endcsname \c@page}\ifx\thepage\foo\else Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    First Page
    \newpage
    Second Page
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    Third Page
    \newpage
    Forth Page
\end{document}
```

**Update -- with some improvements**

It's possible to store the `\thepage` definition when `gobble` is active and compare this later on.

In order to simplify the format to be output, I've defined two hooks, `\@gobble@thepagehook` which should be executed if gobbling is active and `\@nogobble@thepagehook` which comes into action if `gobble` is not set. 
See the relevant code portions please.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% default is 0pt
\fancyhf{}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\makeatletter
\let\gobble@thepage\thepage
\rfoot{%
  \ifx\gobble@thepage\thepage
  \@gobble@thepagehook%
  \else
  \@nogobble@thepagehook%
  \fi
}

%\let\@gobble@thepagehook\relax% For real gobbling
\newcommand{\@gobble@thepagehook}{\textbf{I am gobbled}}% For code golfing :-P
\newcommand{\@nogobble@thepagehook}{%
  Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}%
}

\makeatother
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    First Page
    \newpage
    Second Page
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    Third Page
    \newpage
    Forth Page
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's working :). thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @th1rdey3: Yes, as long as gobbling isn't defined otherwise! Happy TeXing!

Comment: @th1rdey3: I updated my answer with a better version -- it is easier to configure, in my point of view

Comment: that's pretty interesting too, though a little over my head. I would still prefer the one liner.

Comment: @th1rdey3: Regarding the number of upvotes my solution seems to be rubbish ;-) However, you can squeeze the new code in one-line if you wish :D

Answer (score 3):

While `\pagenumbering{gobble}` is a usefull trick in some cases, you should better define a real page style:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% default is 0pt

\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}

\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}

\fancypagestyle{emptywithlines}{%
 \pagestyle{fancy}%
 \rfoot{}}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{emptywithlines}
    First Page
    \newpage
    Second Page
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}% if page numbering should start by 1
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    Third Page
    \newpage
    Forth Page
\end{document}
```