# New command with optional argument being first argument

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I know I can create a new command with an optional parameter with

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[2][Hello]{\textbf{#1} #2}
```

I would like to have the command such that there is an optional parameter which takes the value of the non optional if not specified. Something like this

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[2][#2]{\textbf{#1} #2}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Related Questions: [Different macro behavior when supplied an argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80251/different-macro-behavior-when-supplied-an-argument), and [Different command definitions with and without optional argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument).

Comment: I don't know why this popped up just now, being almost a year old, but it is an exact duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5211/575

Comment: Also, that one has a much better accepted answer than the ones here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### LaTeX kernel solution

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycommand}{\@dblarg\@mycommand}
\def\@mycommand[#1]#2{\textbf{#1} #2}
\makeatother
```

See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56331/4427) for a description of `\@dblarg`.

### `xparse` solution

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{o m}
 {\textbf{\IfValueTF{#1}{#1}{#2}} #2}
```

`\IfValueTF{#1}{A}{B}` looks whether the optional argument was specified; if it was, it delivers `A`, otherwise `B`. In the previous definition, `A` is `#1` and `B` is `#2` as you wished.

The `xparse` solution is more robust.

Answer (score 13):

Using a very elementary approach, you can make the optional argument default to some macro that you can test against:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycommand}[2][\@empty]{%
  \textbf{\ifx\@empty#1\relax#2\else#1\fi} #2}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mycommand{Second} \par
\mycommand[First]{Second}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, the optional argument to `\mycommand` is set to `\@empty` by default (if it's not specified). Using `\ifx\@empty#1\relax`, you can test whether the default argument is supplied (and therefore, `#1` is actually missing). Then, print `#2`, otherwise, print `#1`.