# Different macro behavior when supplied an argument

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I want to define a macro, call it `\func`, so that `\func` will output`\phi`, and `\func[i]` will output `\phi(i)`.

what is the easiest way to achieve this?

I know there are other questions that address this issue - I guess one of them is exactly my question and I just don't get it :)

Comment: Classic LaTeX way uses `\func` and `\func[i]` (note `[...]` instead of `{...}`).

Comment: @PaulGaborit - Thanks, I am quite new to latex :) Will change my question

Comment: @PaulGaborit - BTW, can you refer me to an explanation as to when should one use curly braces and when to use square braces? in this example they use curly braces: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~boas/courses/math696/math-macros.html

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [New command with optional argument being first argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60893/new-command-with-optional-argument-being-first-argument?rq=1), or [Different command definitions with and without optional argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument).

Comment: @noam LaTeX uses `[]` to delimit the _optional_ argument (always the first) of a command. All other arguments use curly braces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define `\func` to take an optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\func[1][]{\phi\ifx\\#1\\\else(#1)\fi}

\begin{document}

$\func\quad\func[i]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But this just exploits the fact that `\phi_{}` looks the same as `\phi`, right? I need a slightly more general solution. I will edit my question to prevent this "loop hole" :)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel right; will do so.

Comment: @noam please see my updated answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina A subscript (even if it's empty) adds a small space after the symbol; its size is in the parameter `\scriptspace`, default value 0.5pt. I've also put a better test in the conditional.

Answer (score 8):

`xparse`-based solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\func}{o}{%
  \phi
  \IfNoValueF{#1}{(#1)}%
}

\begin{document}

$\func\quad\func[i]$

\end{document}
```

where you want a single optional ('`o`-type') argument.