FontAwesome5 How to Add Alt Text to the Icon for Accessibility or Screen Reader?
I am currently working on creating a Resume/CV and using fontawesome5 icons for visual elements such as links to GitHub, LinkedIn, Email, and Phone Number, instead of writing them out as text. I would like to add alt text to the icons for better scanning and accessibility.
I have found several solutions that work well with other packages, such as:

tikz - TikZ: add "alt tag/caption/invisible text" for accessibility and Adding alt text to a Tikz graph
graphicx - How to add "alt text" in Latex
pdftooltip - pdftooltip from pdfcomment package: Using LaTeX code in tooltip

Additionally, I discovered the accsupp package for accessibility support.
Main Question:
How can I add 'alt' text for 'fontawesome'/'fontawesome5' icons or any regular text to make them more readable for screen readers or resume scanners, and what are the best practices for doing so?

I'm not sure what the best practise is, but using accsupp is definitely an option. You can define a new command, for example \faAlt, that takes as argument a fontawesome name, and produces an accsupp block with the icon itself (to be shown in the pdf) and the name as actual text (to be read by a screen reader or an automatic parser).
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand{\faAlt}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=#1}\faIcon{#1}\EndAccSupp{}}
\begin{document}
\faAlt{github} my github

\faAlt{linkedin} my linkedin

\faAlt{envelope} my e-mail

\faAlt{phone} my phone number
\end{document}

Result in a pdf reader:

Result after converting to text (in this case with pdftotext):
github my github
linkedin my linkedin
envelope my e-mail
phone my phone number


The version above assumes that the fontawesome name has the right meaning, which is usually the case but not always, for example here envelope is not the best description for e-mail.
A little bit fancier version with an optional first command that gets used as the ActualText if it is given, and otherwise the regular argument gets used (adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60895/):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\NewDocumentCommand{\faAlt}{o m}{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=\IfValueTF{#1}{#1}{#2}}\faIcon{#2}\EndAccSupp{}}
\begin{document}
\faAlt{github} my github

\faAlt{linkedin} my linkedin

\faAlt[email]{envelope} my e-mail

\faAlt{phone} my phone number
\end{document}

Resulting text:
github my github
linkedin my linkedin
email my e-mail
phone my phone number


that will more or less be read by the inbuilt speech from adobe or foxit (spaces are sometimes missing and you hear e.g. githubmy), but it won't work with e.g. adobe together with NVDA. For this combination you must really tag the PDF, so add \DocumentMetadata{testphase=III} and then you should better add a \leavevmode before the \BeginAccsupp so avoid wrong nesting of tags in the PDF.
