# Using a required argument as a default for an optional one in \newcommand

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I'd like to create a new subsection command with the same calling structure like the original one, but I have no idea on how to handle the case when the optional argument is omitted. Basically I want to have `newsubsection[Short Title]{Long Title}` to call `subsection[#1]{#2}` and `newsubsection{Title}` to call `subsection{#1}`.

I've read [the thread about a similar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5211/how-can-i-use-one-argument-as-the-default-value-for-another) posted here around two years ago, but it seems to have been much more complicated (more than one `opt`-argument) and I'm too much of a TeX-newbie to transfer the solutions to my problem.

Also, I already tried lots of weird combinations like `\newcommand{\subsect}[2][#1]{\par\nolinenumbers\subsection[#1]{#2}\linenumbers}` (failed attempt to use the syntax from the `\wbalTwo`-example [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_commands)), but none of them were resulting in anything remotely working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides an easy interface and conditioning in terms of arguments. The following might be what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,lineno,xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,lineno,xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\sect}{s o m}{%
  \par\nolinenumbers%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\section*{#3}}% \sect*
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\section{#3}}% \sect{...}
      {\section[#2]{#3}}% \sect[..]{...}
    }%
  \linenumbers%
}
\linenumbers
\begin{document} 
\section{First section}\lipsum[8]
\sect{Second section}\lipsum[8]
\end{document}
```

`xparse` provides `\IfBooleanTF` to condition on the presence of the `*` (or `s` macro argument) and `\IfNoValueTF` to condition on the presence of an optional argument (or `o` macro argument).

Although I've demonstrated it with `\section`, it's easy to modify to work with `\subsection` or the like.

Comment: Thanks for this fast, detailed answer including the already ready-made example, which works just as I intended.

Comment: @Big-Blue, I'm trying to use this to declare glossaries with optional inputs, which means that I have to call the macro from the preamble. Doing so gives the `missing \begin{document}` error. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: @Kajsa: You can't call anything that sets content within the preamble. Such things have to occur *after* `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @Werner, Works with `\newcommand` but then I can't make the optional default be one of the mandatory arguments.

Comment: @Kajsa: I don't understand your problem. Perhaps you can post a complete minimal example that replicates the behaviour on [PasteBin](//pastebin.org).

Comment: @Werner, Thank you for suggesting that. The problem was me using the wrong brackets and being unable to see it.

Answer (score 6):

LaTeX has a helper macro `\@dblarg` which is used in sectioning and caption and similar commands for exactly this use: making an optional argument have a default value of the main argument.

```
\makeatletter
\def\newsubsection{\@dblarg\@newsubsection}
\def\@newsubsection[#1]#2{%
\typeout{opt arg: #1}%
\typeout{main arg: #2}%
}

\newsubsection{aaa}

\newsubsection[xxx]{yyy}

\stop
```

Produced a terminal output of

```
opt arg: aaa
main arg: aaa
opt arg: xxx
main arg: yyy
```

Comment: How would you trigger something *after* `\@newsubsection` using `\@dblarg` using your setup? That seems to be what the OP is after.

Comment: @Werner Not sure what you mean `\@newsubsection` could have more than two arguments if you need to pick up more. Or of course it can end with a macro that takes arguments? But the example given in the question doesn't seem to need that?

Comment: @David Carlisle Thanks for providing an alternate method. Unfortunately I am not able to transfer your code to my problem, [here](http://pastebin.com/4R0zeQmi) is what I've tried. Any further advice is appreciated.